# MAAS 1.5 Utopic Boot Image

Tags: maas, 14.10

On a MAAS 1.5 server, I am trying to deploy Utopic boot images with not much luck. After setting the default distro, under UI setting, to Utopic, and pressing import boot images, the following is shown in /var/log/maas/celery.log :

```
[2014-11-06 00:33:54,882: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: provisioningserver.tasks.import_boot_images[ac4e5563-4f66-4730-8b26-551e17e5035a]
[2014-11-06 00:33:55,221: INFO/MainProcess] Task provisioningserver.tasks.import_boot_images[ac4e5563-4f66-4730-8b26-551e17e5035a] succeeded in 0.338499278998s: None
[2014-11-06 00:33:55,221: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: provisioningserver.tasks.report_boot_images[8bbced20-415e-410e-8014-5ee08f37eb7b]
[2014-11-06 00:33:55,289: INFO/MainProcess] Task provisioningserver.tasks.report_boot_images[8bbced20-415e-410e-8014-5ee08f37eb7b] succeeded in 0.0668082359989s: None
```

Evidently, no image new image gets downloaded and Boot Image count remains at 12, i.e., 6 flavours of Trusty and Precise.
Any thoughts as how to deploy Utopic images?
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have defined utopic with the following commands (CLUSTER_UUID is your clusters uuid)

Get the id of boot-sources with:

```
maas <PROFILE> boot-sources read <CLUSTER_UUID>
```

Then get available selections:

```
maas <PROFILE> boot-source-selections read <CLUSTER_UUID> <ID>
```

If you don't have utopic listed, then you create it with:

```
maas <profile> boot-source-selections create <CLUSTER_UUID> <NEW-ID> \
    os=ubuntu release=utopic arches=amd64 subarches=* labels=daily
```

More details about this can be found at "Boot images import configuration" http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/bootsources.html

I hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the above seems to be applicable to maas 1.7 not 1.5, i.e., https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.5/install.html